# ASP.NET / MVC HTML ActionLink - how to pass returned Javascript value to ActionLink routeValue parm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

(target framework is 4.0)

I am implementing a feature to delete multiple records in a simple table. In order to do this, I am using simple HTML checkboxes with a Javascript function to loop through each one to find which are selected. The Javascript is returning an array of int values representing the record IDs to delete.

I am using an ActionLink to call all of this, and to ultimately return to the Delete function (with an int array as a parm) in my controller file to actually submit the deletions to the database.

My problem is, I don't know how to take the array I get back from the Javascript to place into the ActionLink, to pass it into the controller.

Here is the code with which I am working:

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New", "Add") | @Html.ActionLink("Delete Selected", "Delete", new { id = "???" }, new { onclick = "return getProjectsToDelete()" })
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getProjectsToDelete() {

    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete the selected projects?");

    if (answer) {
        var listToDelete = new Array();
        var arrayCount = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < document.projectList.deleteProject.length; i++) {
            if (document.projectList.deleteProject[i].checked) {
                listToDelete[arrayCount] = document.projectList.deleteProject[i].value;
                arrayCount++;
            }
        }

        return listToDelete;
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to push back a collection of IDs to a controller?

In general, this would be done as a FORM and POST the form to the back end. I myself prefer to do this via AJAX but thats just me.

While you can do this using a GET and stuffing all of the IDs in the query string, its dirty!

It would look something like /controller/action?id=7&id=8&id=9

The Model Binder in .NET will convert that in to a List<int> or int[].

I would suggest using ".push" in Javascript to manage you array of IDs. You can also use the ".join" method on your array to create a clean querystring.

Comment: I re-read your code and realize you may not understand how the onclick event works. OnClick is a client side method that is used to execute script on the client side to do some work prior to the click being execute. If your events return "false" the click will abort and the action will not take place. You can not use the OnClick event to return any sort of data to the back end Controller. You can only pass data back via HTTP GET (Querystring of the URL or via AJAX) or HTTP POST (form submission or AJAX)

Remember, the ActionLinks only generate links with URLs based on the routes you setup.